# Seleção específica de coluna em uma tabela HTML no JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá! sou estudante de TI e estou aprendendo sobre Rails.
tenho a seguinte tabela HTML de uma view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Produtos</h1>

<table class="table table-hover custom" id="tabelaProduto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= produto.id %></td>
        <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
        <td><%= produto.preco %></td>
        <td data-jtable><%= produto.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="botaosomar" value="OK" onclick="vamosSomar()" />

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Produto', new_produto_path %>
```

e o JS desta view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabelaProduto tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var value=$(this).find('td').find('preco').html();
        alert(value);
    });
    var tabela = document.getElementById("tabelaProduto");
});
```

esta linha do JS que está sendo minha dúvida:
**var value=$(this).find('td').find('preco').html();**

preciso clicar em uma row da tabela e selecionar APENAS o valor contido no campo "preco" mas estou confuso quanto a esse método "find".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma como está demonstrando essa tabela hoje, só conseguirá recuperar o valor do campo preço pelo índice do elemento `<td>` na `<tr>` e isso só funcionará, levando em consideração que você sempre tenha esse elemento na 3ª posição (ou, posição que definir no jquery, no caso de busca pelo índice).

Quando você escreve: `var value=$(this).find('td').find('preco').html()` até funciona, se: dentro do elemento: `<td>`, você tivesse um elemento: `<preco>`. O que não é o caso.

Sem alterar sem código, e, levando em consideração que o preço sempre estará na 3 posição da tr, tu pode escrever:

```
$("#tabelaProduto tr").click(function(){
   var value = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html();
}
```

O que ele fará será buscar, na tr clicada, o 3 elemento td.

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Mas, de forma mais segura, tu pode alterar um pouco teu html:

```
<tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= produto.id %></td>
        <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
        <td class='preco'><%= produto.preco %></td>
        <td data-jtable><%= produto.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

e seu JS ficaria assim:

```
 $("#tabelaProduto tr").click(function(){
       var value = $(this).find('td.preco').html();
    }
```

Mesmo que tu adicione outras `<td>` em meio a seu código, ele vai sempre buscar pela `<td class='preco'>`

E, se quiser saber mais sobre o find:

https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento! :D